# Java: Why are accessible non-static variables from a static methods outside from the class?

Tags: java

In Java when we want to access a non-static variable from a static method, we get a compile error:

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field nonStatic"

But I made the other class with a static method, and I could reach that non-static variable. Why is this?

So in class A, the line "return nonStatic" and the line "nonStatic=4" is bad. But in the class App method m, and the class B method m is working.

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        A a = new A();
        m( a  );

        System.out.println(a.nonStatic);

    }

    static void m( A a ) {
        a.nonStatic = 12;  //its good...why?

    }
}

class A{

    int nonStatic = 7; 

    static int getOrSetNonStatic(){
        // return nonStatic;  //error
        // nonStatic = 4;     //error
        return 0;
    }

}

class B {

     static void m( A a ) {
            a.nonStatic = 12;   //its good...why?

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes the difference is not the fact that `nonStatic` is accessed from a different class.

Try doing that in A and it will compile:

```
class A {
    int nonStatic = 7; 
     static void m( A a ) {
            a.nonStatic = 12;
     }
}
```

So what makes the difference? It's what you read the static variable on:

- `a.nonStatic` accesses `nonStatic` on an instance. Regardless of where this code is, it is OK.
- Simply typing `nonStatic` in an *instance* (non-static) method inside `A` is *similar* to `a.nonStatic` (i.e., `this.nonStatic`). This is allowed.
- Simply typing `nonStatic` in a *static* method inside `A` is equivalent to `A.nonStatic`, which is a problem regardless of where it's written. `nonStatic` is an instance field, so it cannot be accessed statically (as `A.nonStatic` anywhere, or as `nonStatic` in a static method of `A`)

Answer (score 2):

Because you passed it into the method as an argument.

Maybe it would be clearer if you gave the method parameter a different name. Then you would see that the member field wasn’t visible as a but only under the parameter name.